# I can't npm install express --save

Tags: npm

```
D:\Users\p\myapp>npm install express --save
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'express@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\p\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-24T10_10_58_628Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy of some kind? I can see the latest tag at http://registry.npmjs.org/express just fine from here.

Comment: yes,i do. i'm behind a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be cache error so run below command to fix it

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then try to install it again

Comment: i try to install it again but it not install

Comment: U working offline or connected to Internet? I think u aware of npm install need active internet.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen due to multiple reasons, few I know are listed :

If your internet connection is thru a proxy then you need to configure these, check this link for more information ([enter link description here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/npm-behind-a-proxy-server/19386))  :

```
$ npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
$ npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
```

or else can be this, check & try to set npm registry :

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```